# Hive error: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. stringTypeInfo

Tags: hive, hiveql

Good day, I was going to create a table but there was an error.

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE weblogs(
   host STRING,
   identity STRING,
   customer STRING,
   time STRING,
   request STRING,
   status STRING,
   size STRING,
   referer STRING,
   agent STRING)
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)(?: ([^ \"]*|\".*\") ([^ \"]*|\".*\"))?",
 "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

My error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. stringTypeInfo

I am using apache-hive-1.2.2-bin, derby mode.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wr6r.png)

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: the ddl is working fine.. it got executed .. please check again..

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you really wanted an external table and forgot to specify 'external'. Please try the following:

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE weblogs(
   host STRING,
   identity STRING,
   customer STRING,
   time STRING,
   request STRING,
   status STRING,
   size STRING,
   referer STRING,
   agent STRING)
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\[[^\]]*\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)(?: ([^ \"]*|\".*\") ([^ \"]*|\".*\"))?",
 "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;